# Sqlite аналог оператора :=

Tags: android, android-sdk, sqlite, android-sqlite

Добрый вечер, есть ли аналог оператора MySql := в Sqlite, просто есть запрос, если есть то какой?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  NamePrefix,
  MiddleName,
  Surname,
  @curField := FieldTypeId        AS FieldTypeId,
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ValueTypeId)
   FROM Field
   WHERE FieldTypeId = @curField) AS ValueTypeId,
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Value)
   FROM Field
   WHERE FieldTypeId = @curField) AS Value
FROM ` FieldsToContact` 
INNER JOIN `Field` ON FieldsToContact.FieldId = Field.Id 
INNER JOIN `Contact` ON FieldsToContact.ContactId = Contact.Id
```

Comment: Епрст... Ну нельзя же так выкладывать код! :о И, на сколько я знаю, SQLite совместим с командами MySQL.

Comment: при добавлении в запрос := происходит креш, где sqlite ругается на символ :

Comment: Попробуйте просто `=`

Comment: нет, не то, тогда возвращаются поля равные NULL

Comment: А зачем вам тут вообще переменная ? почему не написать подзапрос в виде `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ValueTypeId)
   FROM Field
   WHERE Field.FieldTypeId = FieldsToContact.FieldTypeId` ?

Answer (score 1):

SQLite не поддерживает создание переменных (обсуждение [здесь](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/how-do-i-declare-and-use-variables-in-sqlite-td26065.html)).

Если очень нужны переменные, то [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14574227/3100967) описывается способ как достичь похожего эффекта с помощью временной таблицы, но в целом проще перестроить запрос, как предлагает Mike в комментарии к вопросу, или выполнить несколько запросов, сохраняя переменные в коде.